# Free particle on a Möbius strip: boundary condition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

I've just see this video ( https://youtu.be/np6_1k99oRA ) and this guy tried to calculate the eigenvalues of a free particles on a Möbius strip using the boundary condition on the rectangle $[-\infty,\infty]\times [-w/2,w/2] $, $\psi(x+L,y)=\psi(x,-y)$ and $\psi(x,\pm w/2)=0$ where $L$ is the length of the strip.

This makes sense to me.

Now let's consider the situation in which the particle can be on one face of the strip or on the opposite face. Here problems arise concerning orientation of the strip but, despite the fact that the strip is not orientable, it is however locally orientable (each point has an orientable neighborhood).

In other words now the particle can go to the other face of the strip in two ways.

- run across the entire strip
- go to the other face of the strip by tunnel effect

In other words I'm thinking about 3 sheets with the Möbius strip boundary condition: in 2 of this the particle is free to move, the third is placed between the others and on this sheet is placed a delta potential.

So I would schematize the situation considering a domain $ [-\infty,\infty] \times [-w/2,w/2] \times[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ with the boundary condition $\psi(x,\pm w/2,z)=\psi(x,y,\pm \epsilon)=0$ and $\psi(x+L,y,z)=\psi(x,-y,-z)$. I would define a potential like $V(z)=\delta(z)$

The questions are:

1. If this reasoning is right how can I bring back to the case of unions of 2 dimensional spaces (the 3 sheets)? when and how I can do the limit $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\psi$?
2. If we think about the strip as "union of 3 sheets" we are considering a non-connected space and a particle that can "jump" between non-connected components. This is so strange. Has it any sense? Is there a way to bypass this problem?
3. If our purpose is to calculate the probability that the particle travels along a length $L$ without go to the other face  ($z \to -z$) by tunnel effect, what we have to do?
4. Is there a way to solve the problem without introduce the third dimension? (with appropriate boundary condition on the rectangle $[-\infty,\infty]\times [-w/2,w/2] $ (or on other domains)
5. If the answer to the 4. is "yes", what are the appropriate boundary condition?
6. Physically, what non-orientability implies?

Comment: The second boundary condition is no weirder than the infinite potential well, which we treat in the first chapter of a QM textbook.

Comment: the Moebius strip does not have an "other" side.

Answer (score 3):

> This condition means that the particle is free to flip on the other side of the strip and this sounds weird to me.

I have no idea what you mean by this, but it seems to me that if you're talking about "sides" of a Möbius strip then you're already going wrong. The conditions you're talking about are obviously describing a particle on the 'flat', [topological Möbius strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip#Topology), which you get by identifying two opposing edges of the unit square.

Frankly, the important part of the Möbius-strip qualifier is the requirement that
$$
\psi(x+L,y) = \psi(x,-y),
$$
i.e. that a translation in one direction completely flips space in the orthogonal dimension. What you do along that dimension is frankly pretty irrelevant, but your elaborations (particularly your first proposal) sound pretty pointless to me.

---

Edit: your updated question, in the formulation

> In other words now the particle can go to the other face of the strip in two ways.
>
> - run across the entire strip
> - go to the other face of the strip by tunnel effect

does make enough sense to be answerable, though your attempts to do so are going in the wrong direction. The place where you go wrong is in your proposed domain,

> i would schematize the situation considering a domain $ [-\infty,\infty] \times [-w/2,w/2] \times[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$

which is a three-dimensional domain that's attempting to model a fundamentally two-dimensional object.

What you need, ultimately, is two different copies of the unit square, to model the two different faces of the unit square ($\cong$ rectangle) that you twist and glue to make the Möbius strip. The answer is the obvious one: just make two copies explicitly! The right domain is thus
$$
\mathcal D =  [-\infty,\infty] \times [-w/2,w/2] \times \{1,-1\},
$$
a continuous domain in direct product with a discrete set of cardinality $2$. Thus, your wavefunction is an object of the form $\psi_i(x,y)$, where $i=1,2$, $x \mathbb R/L$ and $-w/2\leq y\leq w/2$.

To finish up, you need two things:

1. The boundary conditions, which are given by
   $$
   \psi_i(x+L,y) = \psi_{-i}(x,-y),
   \tag 1
   $$
   i.e., a translation by $L$ flips the orientation of the $y$ axis, and it also changes which face of the strip you're on. (Want to convince yourself that this is the right approach? Cut up a long strip of paper and draw a set of $x,y$ axes on one face and label it $1$. Then turn it around, label the other face $2$, and draw a set of axes directly tracing the ones on the other side. Then form the Möbius strip, and you'll see how the two coordinate patches connect as in $(1)$.)
2. The hamiltonian, which will account for the free-particle motion as well as the tunnelling from one face to the other. This is dead simple:
   $$
   \hat H \psi_i(x,y) = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \psi_i(x,y) +t\,\psi_{-i}(x,y),
   \tag 2
   $$
   where $t$ is a tunnelling constant with dimensions of energy.

That's all you need. I'll leave it to you to work out the eigenfunctions of this problem.

Comment: I do all this because I'm thinking about a mobius strip made of matter. In this case the particle have a non null probability to go to the to the  "other side" without travel all the strips.

Comment: "made of matter" means that there is a potential along the strip that can interact with the state with the particle. You can see every atom of the strip like a source of a coulomb potential. So the case 2 and 3 is a way to simplify the potential

Comment: "a mobius strip made of matter" is not a sufficient description to do anything useful.

Comment: The case 1 is because I see the strip with a width of w/2 and the rectangle that rappresent the two side of the strip on the upper side and on the lower side

Comment: Ok let's change point of view. We put the strip in R3 and we define a potential that is 0 everywhere but constant and positive on the strip so we have a discontinuity of potential between the 2 sides of the strips. I'm thinking about panticle on the strip not in the strip, I don't know if this has any sense

Comment: Case 1 is not a Möbius strip - it is a topological cylinder with a nonstandard mapping from the plane.

Comment: I don't have time for extended back-and-forth for you to come up with a well-defined problem (which should in any case happen in [chat] and not in a comment thread). Produce a clear question, edit it into the question post, and if it's well-defined enough I'll respond with an edit.

Comment: I've edited the post but now it seems a totally different question. I've explain better what i meant and i've add some details.

Comment: @PieroViscone See the edits to this answer.

Comment: Probably a silly confusion but I think we should work with the identification $\psi_i(x+L,y) = \psi_{-i}(x,-y)$ even if $t=0$, right? As in I don't understand why the identification $\psi(x+L,y) = \psi(x,-y)$ is correct if we are not talking about any tunneling.

Answer (score -2):

It makes no sense to talk about a free particle on a Möbius strip because a Möbius strip has a boundary that constrains the “free” particle. This is an oxymoron. For example, a particle in a box is not “free”; it is *trapped* by an *infinite potential* at the walls. (“Free *inside*”, which the OP did not state, is not the same as “free”, which the OP did state.) What makes sense is a free particle in a Klein bottle, which has no boundary.

The boundary conditions for a free particle in a Klein bottle with coordinates in $[0,W]\times[0,H]$ should be

$$\psi(0,y)=\psi(W,H-y),$$

$$\psi(x,0)=\psi(x,H).$$

You want to think of a Klein bottle as a “twisted” torus where two of the opposite edges are identified, running in the same direction, and the other two are identified, but running in the opposite direction.

Comment: "Taking one finite and one infinite is weird" That's what a Möbius strip is though. You are describing a Klein bottle

Comment: @octonion [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_strip#Topology) says a Möbius strip  can be defined as a square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$...

Comment: I'm talking about the boundary. In that Wikipedia page one pair of sides are not connected. You connected them.

Comment: You can’t have a free particle if there is a boundary. The entire premise of the question is wrong. I will revise my answer,

Comment: @octonion Do you agree or disagree with my revised answer?

Comment: Well I wasn't going to comment, but if you ask directly, I think saying a particle with reflecting boundary conditions is not free is purely semantics, and given OP's question is about these boundary conditions I think it's not very useful.

Comment: @octonion From my point of view, requiring the wavefunction to vanish on two sides is equivalent to saying that there is infinite potential there, so it isn’t free. Is that an invalid point of view for some reason?

Comment: Yes I know what you mean, hence my comment to OP. You aren't saying anything incorrect.

Comment: @octonion Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Sorry, with "free particle" I mean a particle that is free to move on the manifold and nowhere else.

Comment: I find this answer to be pointless sticking to semantics. It is perfectly reasonable to talk about a free particle constrained to a finite region, and the existence of boundary regions does not impede that. There is nothing oxymoronic about discussions of a free particle on a Möbius strip.